# Is there a redundancy between the two functions of adding a start node and an end node to my graph?

Tags: python

I feel like there is a redundency between:

```py
def _determine_nodes_with_no_predecessors(nodes:List[Node])->List[str]:
    """
    Given the list of nodes returns the identifiers of nodes that doesn't have any predecessor. 
    """
    nodes_ids_without_prdecessors = []
    for node in nodes:
        if not node.predecessors: 
            nodes_ids_without_prdecessors.append(node.id_)
    return nodes_ids_without_prdecessors


def _add_start_node(graph:Graph):

    start_node = Node.create_start_node(graph)

    graph.add_node(start_node)

    nodes_ids_without_prdecessors = _determine_nodes_with_no_predecessors(graph.nodes)
    
    # Its successors are the nodes without predecessors in this graph
    for node_id in nodes_ids_without_prdecessors: 
        start_node.add_successor(graph.nodes[node_id])
            
    # Conversly, We add the `start_node` as a predecessor to the nodes without predecessors in this graph
    for node_id in nodes_ids_without_prdecessors: 
        node = graph.nodes[node_id]
        node.add_predecessor(start_node)
```

And this one:

```py
def _determine_nodes_with_no_successors(nodes:List[Node])->List[str]:
    """
    Given the list of nodes returns the identifiers of nodes that doesn't have any successor. 
    """
    nodes_ids_without_successors = []
    for node in nodes:
        if not node.successors: 
            nodes_ids_without_successors.append(node.id_)
    return nodes_ids_without_successors

def _add_end_node(graph:Graph):
    
    end_node = Node.create_end_node() #constructor of node
    
    graph.add_node(end_node)
    
    end_node = graph.nodes[end_node.id_]

    nodes_ids_without_successors = _determine_nodes_with_no_successors(graph.nodes)

    # Its predecessors are the nodes without successors in this graph
    for node_id in nodes_ids_without_successors: 
        end_node.add_predecessor(graph.nodes[node_id])
            
    # Conversly, We add the `end_node` as a predecessor to the nodes without predecessors in this graph
    for node_id in nodes_ids_without_successors: 
        node = graph.nodes[node_id]
        node.add_successor(end_node)
```

Note: `Node` is a class that have the attributes `predecessors`, `successors` and `id_` and the class methods `create_dummy_start_node`, `create_dummy_end_node`, `add_predecessor` and `add_successor`. `Graph` is a class that have the attribute `nodes` and the method `add node`.

How to write less code in this case? Is it possible to write only two functions that do the whole stuff (instead of four functions)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr) function to extract an attribute by name. Likewise the `setattr` function to set attributes.

This means you can pass the name of the attribute to a private function, unifying the code:

```
def _find_nodes_with_no(pred_succ: str, nodes: List[Node]) -> List[Node]:
    """ Find nodes with either no predecessors, or no successors. """

    if pred_succ not in ("predecessors", "successors"):
        raise ValueError("pred_succ must be either 'predecessors' or 'successors'")

    return [node for node in nodes if not getattr(node, pred_succ)]
```

Your `add_start` and `add_end` functions can thus be written to pass the appropriate names:

```
def add_start(graph: Graph):
    info = ("create_start_node", "predecessors", "successors")
    _add_outer_node(graph, info)

def add_end(graph: Graph):
    info = ("create_end_node", "successors", "predecessors")
    _add_outer_node(graph, info)
```

Then in `_add_outer_node` you can do things like:

```
cmeth, main_links, back_links = info
create_method = getattr(Node, cmeth)
new_node = create_method(graph)

# ...

outer_nodes = _find_nodes_with_no(main_links, graph)
```

One thing I do question it your "manual" connection of both the predecessor and successor links. It seems like you want those to be reflexive, so why not create an `add_predecessor` method that automatically creates the reciprocal link? Likewise with `add_successor`?

Answer (score 0):

Since there's only two cases, the strategy pattern should be sufficient. Alternatively, creating an inverted view of the graph would allow you to implement `_add_end_node()` by calling `_add_start_node()` on the inverted graph view.

```
class StartNodeStrategy:
    def create_node(self):
        return Node.create_start_node()
    def find_hanging(self,nodes):
        return [
            node.id_
            for node in nodes
            if not node.predecessor
        ]
    def fix_hanging(self,outer_node,inner_node):
        inner_node.add_predecessor(outer_node)
        outer_node.add_successor(inner_node)

class EndNodeStrategy:
    def create_node(self):
        return Node.create_end_node()
    def find_hanging(self,nodes):
        return [
            node.id_
            for node in nodes
            if not node.successor
        ]
    def fix_hanging(self,outer_node,inner_node):
        inner_node.add_successor(outer_node)
        outer_node.add_predecessor(inner_node)


def _add_outer_node(graph:Graph,strategy):
    
    outer_node = strategy.create_node()
    graph.add_node(outer_node)
    outer_node = graph.nodes[outer_node.id_]

    for inner_node in strategy.find_hanging(graph.nodes):
        strategy.fix_hanging(outer_node,inner_node)
```